# Power Automate , Email formatting to Table

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I send an automated email with power automate/flow.
How can I put these lines into a table format?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use below in the Body Of send email action:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
       <td>Project ID</td>
       <td>Project Name</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ProjectID']}</td>    
       <td>@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ProjectName']}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Example:
[image]

[image]